# Sorting an object by its subobject

Tags: c++, sorting, object

I would like to sort the list extnodeID based off the nodeids that extnodeID is referencing.
Code will probably have mistakes as it's just an example

```
class Node {
    public:
            int nodeID;                 /* unique node ID */
            std::list<int> extnodeID;   /* the node ID of other nodes */
            int length;                 /* non-unique value */
}

int main(){
    std::vector<Node> nodes;

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
       Node tempnode;
       tempnode.nodeID = i;
       length = rand() % 6;
     }
       
}
```

For example:

Node 0:
nodeID = 0;
extnodeID = {1,2};

Node 1:
nodeID = 1;
length = 3;

Node 2:
nodeID = 2;
length = 5;

Since length of Node 2 is higher than Node 1 the result will be:

Node 0:
nodeID = 0
extnodeID = **{2,1}**

Comment: What's your question Lucas?

Comment: I would like to know how to sort the extnodeIDs based off the length that those extnodeIDs represent.

Comment: Have you had a look at `std::sort` and a few examples?

Comment: use `std::sort` and pass your comparator function in 3rd argument and write your sorting logic in that function. then if you encounter any problem then attach that comparator code too in your question. thanks